# My switch case system isn't working out in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement

I am new to Python. I recently learnt that there wasn't a switch case system for python. Instead, the programmer has to make one using the dictionary data type.

I wanted to make a menu system using switch case and the code goes like this :

```
switch={'1':func1(),'2':func2()} #func1() and func2() are two separate functions (menu options)
choice= input('choice : ')
switch[choice]
```

Well, in my switch system no matter what I input as 'choice' , **func1()** runs only.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are the functions supposed to be called when populating the dictionary? The way you have it setup, both func1 and func2 will run before you even ask for input. If not; remove the parenthesis on the functions. That will store a reference to each function (not the result of the function itself).

Comment: You can also use a bunch of `elif` clauses which is pretty much what a `switch` statement does anyway (assuming `break;` in each case statement).

Comment: @RobertKearns removing the parenthesis actually worked. Can you please elaborate a bit more on the same. Any source of information will also help. Sorry to trouble you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, it looks like both func1 and func2 will run every time the code runs. The problem is that when you are declaring your dictionary, you are executing/calling the functions (since you have the `()` after the function name, which is how functions are "called"), instead of just storing a link/reference to them.

In order to pass/store a reference to a function without calling it, just type its name, without `()` at the end. Then, to call a function that was referenced in a variable/somewhere, add the parenthesizes.

This should work:

```py
switch = {'1': func1, '2': func2} # func1() and func2() are two separate functions (menu options)
choice = input('choice : ')
switch[choice]()
```

Notice how I removed the `()` from the functions on the first line. Also notice on the last line that I am calling the function that is stored in `switch` with the key `choice`, by adding `()` at the end.

Comment: just to clarify... when I write the function name without '()', Python just makes a note that the named function exists without executing it and as soon as I put '()', Python executes it?
Apart from this instance is there any other example where this feature can come in handy?

Comment: Think of the name of a function as a variable that contains a "link" to the function code. If you want to execute the code at the link you add `()`, which is referred to as calling it. However, if you just want to store the link in e.g. a different variable, or maybe pass it to another function, you don't add the `()`. This can come in handy when you're writing code that is supposed to be very dynamic/flexible. Or when doing something simple as a dictionary of functions to execute (like you). Here's some reading on it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-function-as-an-argument-in-python/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting `func1()` in the dictionary, try putting `func1` (no parentheses).

```py
>>> switch = {'1' : func1,         # No parentheses here
...           '2' : func2 }        # ...or here.
>>> choice = input('choice : ')
>>> switch[choice]()               # But do put parentheses here.
```

By putting `func1()` in the dictionary, you are actually calling that function and storing its *result* in the dictionary. If instead you want to call the function through the dictionary, you need to store the function *handle* (its variable name) and call it after indexing into `switch`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But can you please tell me what's  the logic behind removing the parentheses inside the switch and getting them back afterwards.

Comment: The parenthesis call the function. If you put the parenthesis in your dictionary, the function is called when creating the dictionary.

Comment: @RobertKearns Is there any other situation apart from this in which this feature comes in handy ?

Comment: being able to refer to functions without evaluating them is used all over the place, e.g. calling `map(int, '1 2 3'.split())`, decorators, Python's entire object system it built around them